# How can I make private ActiveRecord db attribute in Yii2?

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

For example I have a model Person that was created from db table 'person' with fields 'firstname' and 'lastname' using Gii model generator. 
I can access these attributes like

```
$person = Person::findOne($PersonId);
$personFirstname = $person->firstname;
```

If i created custom attribute `fullname` using getters and setters:

```
public function getFullname()
{
    return $this->firstname .' '.$this->lastname
}
```

I don't need 'firstname' and 'lastname' anymore. I i would like to hide them. Make private. How can I do that?

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve your goal create new model and extend his from `Person`. And set property which you need. How it works see [this](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/frontend/models/SignupForm.php) and [this](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/common/models/LoginForm.php).

Comment: Hmm.. In these examples classes are extended from Model class, not from ActiveRecord.  In ActiveRecord 'firstname' and 'lastname' are virtual attributes.